# Shading options using pcolor and pcolormesh with datetime data - date interpolation issues

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, heatmap

I have a large dataset with temperature at different heights at different times.
I wish to plot this as a heatmap using pcolormesh.

When I do so I get a warning that `MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: shading='flat' when X and Y have the same dimensions as C is deprecated since 3.3.  Either specify the corners of the quadrilaterals with X and Y, or pass shading='auto', 'nearest' or 'gouraud', or set rcParams['pcolor.shading'].  This will become an error two minor releases later.`

As a result I try and pass the option `shading='nearest'` to make sure I retain all my data (`shading='flat'` deletes a row and column). This gives me an error of the form `numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'greater_equal' input 0 from dtype('<m8[ns]') to dtype('<m8') with casting rule 'same_kind'`.

It seems to me that there are issues with applying interpolation for the quadrilateral corners to date data (I can see this would be tricky to do) but I have been searching and cannot find a way to make this work. I could try converting the dates entirely to seconds and interpolating as an integer, but I want to have its current form on the axis ticks.

Is there a simple solution?
TIA

A simple snippet to replicate the error is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
data = [
        ['2018-12-26 00:00:00',0,5,10],
        ['2018-12-26 06:00:00',1,6,9 ],
        ['2018-12-26 12:00:00',2,7,8 ],
        ['2018-12-26 18:00:00',3,8,7 ],
        ['2018-12-27 00:00:00',4,9,6 ],
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['date', 0, 10, 20]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
dates = df['date']
heights = df.iloc[:,1:].columns
temp = df.iloc[:,1:].transpose()
fig = plt.figure()
im = plt.pcolormesh(dates, heights, temp,
                      shading='nearest')
```

Comment: So 1) please report this to matplotlib, because this should probably be fixed.  2) you can of course specify the edges of the bins yourself and avoid this problem.  Something like `edges = [datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 25, 18, 0, 0) + datetime.timedelta(hours=6*i) for i in range(6)]`

Comment: Actually the above is fixed on matplotlib and will be in v3.3.3 and v3.4 when released: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18547

Comment: Ah, fantastic. Hopefully v3.3.3 should drop quite soon. For now I'll make a temporary workaround specifying the edges.

Comment: Same problem here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Jody Klymak in the comments above, this issue has been addressed in a newer version of Matplotlib.

I am running version 3.3.3 and my original code now runs without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html) library for creating heatmaps.

**Here's my solution using your sample data:**

```py
# Import packages
import seaborn 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create sample data
data = [
        ['2018-12-26 00:00:00',0,5,10],
        ['2018-12-26 06:00:00',1,6,9 ],
        ['2018-12-26 12:00:00',2,7,8 ],
        ['2018-12-26 18:00:00',3,8,7 ],
        ['2018-12-27 00:00:00',4,9,6 ],
       ]

# Load sample into dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['date', 0, 10, 20]
temp = df.iloc[:,1:].transpose()

# Convert data to numpy array, AND flip the data (and later y tick labels) 
# so that the height is in increasing order from bottom to top in the heatmap
data2 = temp.to_numpy()
data2 = np.flip(data2, axis=0)

# Create empty figure
plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))

# Create heatmap (with customized colorscales, x/y ticks, line color, etc.)
seaborn.heatmap(data2, annot=True, linewidths=.5, linecolor='k', square=False, 
                     xticklabels=df.date, yticklabels=np.flip(temp.index), cbar_kws={'label': 'Temperature'},
                     vmin=np.amin(data2), vmax=np.amax(data2), cmap='hot')

# Add axis labels/rotations and title to the plot
plt.title('Temperature at Different Heights and Times')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
plt.ylabel('Height')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

I was able to use the full datetime string as the x ticks. Also since you're dealing with temperatures, I chose the 'Hot' colorscale.

**Here is the output of my code:**
[image: Heatmap]

Comment: Seaborn is nice, and is a reasonable solution, the only issue is that it isn't included in my project's virtual environment, so I was looking for a matplotlib based solution. Is there an alternative to pcolormesh for this purpose at all?

Comment: @FluidFox I know [pcolor](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.pcolor) is a predecessor of pcolormesh, but I think it is deprecated now. I was able to create a rough plot with `plt.pcolormesh(np.flip(data2, axis=0), cmap='hot')` which has the same colors as my plot above but without the labels (apparently adding such labels would be difficult too). Also, is there no way you can install new packages in your virtual environment?

Comment: I can see, but its for a large organisation who have quite strict code guidelines. I managed to get a solution using just the temperature data and pcolormesh as you suggest here, but I want to have the height and date associated with it to obtain axis labels and correct spacings.